# RDL Renderer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rdl

All,

Is there a third party application / open source etc that renders RDL (Report Definition Language) to WPF? We are not happy with the presentation Reporting Services provides so thinking of using the RDL and render it in WPF.

Thanks,

MK

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion is having a RDL based report render for Wpf called ReportViewer.

HTH